# PC boots but screen is off. Need to reboot several times before video works again

Tags: video, freeze, hardware-failure

I have this problem with my PC. First setup:

- Asus P5E Deluxe Motherboard (first BIOS, I've never update it)
- 4Gb DDR2 RAM Corsair XMS 2 (2x2Gb)
- MSI Ati Radeon 4850
- Velociraptor 150Gb 10000 RPM
- Windows 7 Professional 64 bits
- Corsair VX550W PSU

So almost everyday my computer will freeze and I have to shut it off by holding the power button. Once that's happened, my computer boots normally but the monitors have no signal, all the way from the BIOS to Windows. I know it boots normally because I can hear the welcome sounds of Windows 7. And to shut it off I log in Windows and then hit ALT+F4 then ENTER and she will shut off normally.

These freezes will happen during normal use, I hardly do gaming with my computer nowadays.

Now, after I do this boot and shut off with no signal from the monitors like ten times, the video card will send signal again (I guess) and I can keep working. Until it freezes again, wich can be the same day, or next day. Is not that frequent, but is incredibly annoying.

Windows 7 doesn't even know the computer freezes. The event viewer only detects that the power was cut off. It doesn't record any problem with the video card or any other device.

So I don't know what to do now. I bought the Velociraptor thinking it was the hard drive (this was before I discovered the welcome sounds). Change the OS from Vista 32 to Win7 64. Change the power cable of the video card (the video card is always on, the fan is spining every single time I turn the computer on).

My machine has worked well since Feb 2009 until now. Should I update the BIOS? Change the video card? Change the motherboard?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact your displays are playing up and your computer is freezing, to me, indicates a **video card hardware issue**. I'd replace the video card first.

I wouldn't think updating/flashing the BIOS would make a difference and I'd only recommend replacing the motherboard as a last resort.

Comment: You should always get some type of signal to the monitor when you boot up. If you are not getting a signal I would start with the video card, but I would still test the monitor on another machine just to be sure. I still believe that the video card is causing the crashing though. If you are not gaming, you can get a cheap card for under $50.

Comment: All right guys, I'll try a new video card. When installed, I'll post how it worked out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well changed the video card. Haven't had a problem since. What made me wonder about if it was the video card was the fact that after rebooting several times the thing worked. Really don't get it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it's working. :)